Spring boot 3.2.5 when in @RestControllerAdvice jakarta.servlet.error.status_code and jakarta.servlet.error.request_uri are not set in WebRequest
I'm trying to return the default response of spring boot but I want to log the exception I wrote:
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalculatorController.class);


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
    public Map<String, Object> handleMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex, WebRequest request) {
        DefaultErrorAttributes error = new DefaultErrorAttributes();
        return error.getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public Map<String, Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("Exception: ", ex);
        DefaultErrorAttributes error = new DefaultErrorAttributes();
        return error.getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
    }

when I don't go in the @RestControllerAdvice the path and the status of org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.DefaultErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions options) are correctly setted, but when I cacth the exception in the controller advice they are null these are the propery read for status and path:
this.getAttribute(requestAttributes, "jakarta.servlet.error.status_code");
this.getAttribute(requestAttributes, "jakarta.servlet.error.request_uri");

does someone know how to return the standare error message? I just want to log the exception

Here we have the question with close problem and you can find an answer with a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64138232/2556249
To keep standard error message you need to manually add values to WebRequest attibutes.
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalculatorController.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
    public Map<String, Object> handleMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex, WebRequest request) {
        // Here you add error status code
        webRequest.setAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        // Here we add request URI and this could be a bit tricky
        webRequest.setAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, ((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest().getRequestURI(), RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);

        DefaultErrorAttributes error = new DefaultErrorAttributes();
        return error.getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
    }
}

When I faced with these problem I started to read from this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30828 and then travelled through a billion of links. As far as I understood the problem  these fields are populated by only if passing request to embedded /error controller.
